# Concrete example to illustrate the theory about blocks of groups with cyclic defect groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

I'd like to to have a concrete example to illustrate the theory about blocks of groups with cyclic defect groups.

Thus, I am looking for a finite group $G$ and a prime $p$ dividing $|G|$ satisfying all of the following properites:

- The defect group $D$ of a $p$-block $B$ of $G$ is cyclic and of order $p^r$, where $r\geq 2$
- $G$ is neither $p$-solvable nor solvable (or at least not solvable)
- The shape of the graph of the Brauer tree associated to $B$ is not only a (part of a) star, but more complicated (and, if it doesn't make things too complicated, the Brauer tree associated to $B$ has an exceptional vertex)
- All inclusions are proper in the chain $1 \leq D_1 \leq D\cong C_{p^r} \leq N_G(D)\leq N_G(D_1)\leq G $, where $D_1$ is the unique subgroup of $D$ of order $p$
- All inclusions are proper in the chain $C_G(D_1) \leq T(c) \leq N_G(D_1)$
- It is still possible to express these groups relatively nicely, such that one does not have to say that some group is an extension of a semidirect product of the double cover of the first non-split extension of... with ...of...

**Remark for the penultimate point:** Let $b$ be the block of $N_G(D_1)$ which is Brauer-correspondent to $B$, let $c$ be a block of $C_G(D_1)$ covered by $b$ and let $T(c)$ be the inertial goup.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such an example. Neither was I able to construct one.

If it is not possible to find an example with all inclusions proper, then maybe with not all but many of them?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: Thank you very much for the comment. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I think the fourth bulletpoint, especially the requirement that that $N_{G}(D) < N_{G}(D_{1})$ may be the most difficult to realise (given that $G$ is not $p$-solvable). I may write a formal answer later.

Answer (score 6):

You probably know this, but your conditions can't be met by any principal $p$-block of any finite group $G$ which is not $p$-solvable, although I think the Classification of Finite Simple Groups (CFSG) is necessary for that. For suppose that $G$ is a finite group with cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup $D$ and with $|D| >p,$  but that $G$ is not $p$-solvable. Then the principal $p$-block $B$ of $G$ has defect group $D$, and this does not change on passage to $G/O_{p^{\prime}}(G),$ so we might as well suppose that $O_{p^{\prime}}(G) = 1.$ Now $O_{p}(G) = 1,$ for otherwise we have $D_{1} \lhd G,$ and then $C_{G}(D_{1}) \lhd G.$ But $C_{G}(D_{1})$ has a (characteristic) normal $p$-complement ( which must be trivial) as $O_{p^{\prime}}(G) = 1.$ Then $C_{G}(D_{1}) = D \lhd G,$ and $G$ is certainly $p$-solvable, a contradiction.

Let $H$ be a Hall $p^{\prime}$-subgroup of $N_{G}(D).$ Then $D = [D,H] \times C_{D}(H)$ since $D$ is Abelian of order coprime to $|H|$. Since $D$ is cyclic, we either have $C_{D}(H) = D$ or $C_{D}(H) = 1.$ In the former case, $N_{G}(D)$ has a normal $p$-complement, and then so does $G,$ contrary to the fact that $G$ is not $p$-solvable. Hence $D = [D,H] \leq G^{\prime}.$

Now $G^{\prime}$ is not $p$-solvable, as $G$ is not, so we then obtain $D \leq G^{\prime \prime}$ by the same argument, and ultimately $D \leq G^{(\infty)},$ the terminal member of the derived series for  $G$, by repeating the argument.

Let $M$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G.$ Then $M$ has order divisible by $p$, so that $D_{1} \leq M.$ Also $M$ is not a $p$-group, so $M$ is non-Abelian simple (using the fact that $M$ has cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup). Then $G = MN_{G}(D_{1})$ by a Frattini (type) argument.Now $MC_{G}(D_{1}) \lhd G$ and $G/MC_{G}(D_{1})$ is a homomorphic image of the Abelian $p^{\prime}$-group  $N_{G}(D_{1})/C_{G}(D_{1}),$ so is itself Abelian of order prime to $p$.

Now we have $D \leq MC_{G}(D_{1})$ and $MC_{G}(D_{1})/M$ (being a homomorphic image of $C_{G}(D_{1})$ ) has a normal $p$-complement. But $MC_{G}(D_{1})$ is certainly not $p$-solvable, so arguing as before, we have $D \leq [MC_{G}(D_{1})]^{\prime}.$ Hence $MC_{G}(D_{1})$ has no factor group of order $p$, so that $MC_{G}(D_{1})/M$ is a $p^{\prime}$-group. Now $G/M$ is a $p^{\prime}$-group, so that $D \leq M.$

Now $G = MN_{G}(D)$ by a Frattini argument. I claim that we now have $N_{G}(D) = N_{G}(D_{1}).$ This is the (first and only) time we require CFSG, though the previous argument could have been shortened considerably using CFSG.

Note that $N_{G}(D_{1}) = N_{M}(D_{1})N_{G}(D),$ so to prove the claim, it suffices to prove that $N_{M}(D_{1}) = N_{M}(D).$ But it is a Theorem of H. Blau that whenever a finite non-Abelian simple group $X$ has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup $P \neq 1$, then $P$ is TI in $X$, that is, $P \cap P^{x} = 1$ for all $x \in X \backslash N_{X}(P)$.

In our situation, this immediately yields that $N_{M}(D_{1}) = N_{M}(D),$ as required. Hence your fourth bulletpoint can't be satisfied (for principal blocks of non-$p$-solvable groups) as remarked in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the explanations and the very elegant proof. May I kindly ask, whether you happen to know an example, where not all, but many inclusions are proper? For instance, I considered $G=$PSL(3,8) and $p=3$, but there $[N_G(D_1):C_G(D_1)]=2$, so I don't have that the inclusions in the second chain are proper, what I'd really be fond of to have.

Comment: I'll think a little, but you might find an example of a block with cyclic defect group of a simple group $S$ such that the block is not stable in ${\rm Aut}(S)$ (such a block would have to be non-principal).